# is it possible to change the thickness of the border around an ImageButton in android?

Tags: android, imagebutton

im trying to increase the size of the picture in an ImageButton without changing the size of the button, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can increase it by adding padding for button layout. See my sample XML code has the padding

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Text"
   android:padding="20dp"
   android:background="@drawable/my_button"
   />
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested here, but now the button except for the image disappears completely.  i want to keep the button there, just have the edge of the image go to the edge of the button. i am using a circle as the image.

Comment: Then you need to use shape as an background image  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/package-summary.html